# Discord.py block the rest of my program to run

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I'm trying to create a a bot that connects to multiple chats (Twich and discord for now and youtube in the future.) I found this code online and made it work but I have a hard time understanding async function. My problem is when I use this function (witch is inside a class) my main loop get "stuck" at on_message.

The good news is that I can receive message from discord, the bad news is that because the code get "stuck" there, I'll never reach the section in my main loop that check and deals with message from Twich.

Any help getting unstuck would be nice.

```
def connection(self):
        print("Connecting...")
        # Connect to Twitch chat using WebSocket
        try:
            self.intents = discord.Intents.all()
            self.client = discord.Client(command_prefix='!', intents=self.intents)

            @self.client.event
            async def on_ready():
                print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(self.client))

            @self.client.event
            async def on_message(message):

                if message.author == self.client.user:
                    return

                if message.content.startswith('hi'):
                    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

            self.client.run(self.oauth_token)

            listOfConnection.append(self)

        except OverflowError as e:
            raise DiscordConnectionError(str(e))


        print("Connection Successful")
        return self`
```

FYI I use websocket for twich and I have a loop that check if there's a new message. And the purpose of the program is basically

Check if you have a new message from multiple sources

for each new messages, check if they meet my criteria

If yes, do something

Repeat until the end of the world

I tried to understand asyncio but I'm not even sure if it would solve my problem. And now I have a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the websocket async like described in the [Websocket Documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/intro.html)

```py
async def hello():
        async with websockets.connect(
            'ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        print(f"> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")
```

which you can just directly run in an async bot function. For running the async websocket connection in a non async function you need to create an async event loop and run the function in it

`asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())`

Alternatively could you use [Threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) but that would need you to build a local socket server e.g. with aiohttp and is the more complicated way.